# spring integration to read emails with multiple instances of spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, containers, spring-integration

I run a spring boot application using below configuration to read emails from a given email account. However, this springboot application is containerized and hence we have multiple instances of this application running at a given time.

My question is, Do multiple consumers[app instances] will get same message to process from the email account or it would not be available to other consumers[app instances] if anyone of the consumer reads it? I am trying to avoid duplicate processing of messages.

Configuration xml -

```
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                      store-uri="imaps://abc.com/INBOX"
                                      channel="receiveChannel"
                                      should-delete-messages="false"
                                      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                                      auto-startup="true">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="600000" />

    </int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.protocols">TLSv1.2</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="mailService" class="com.xpressbees.poller.EmailPoller"/>

    <int:service-activator id="serviceActivator" input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="mailService" method="handleMail"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `should-mark-messages-as-read="true"` is enough for IMAP mail receiver to skip those messages on other instances or for subsequent fetch: `NotTerm notSeen = new NotTerm(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true));`.

Do you observe some other behavior?

**UPDATE**

You also can use a leader election feature from Spring Integration, where only one active instance is going to pull mail box: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#leadership-event-handling. Another feature is to use an Idempotent Receiver advice to prevent duplicates: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver

Comment: Yes, I think this is the good approach too, when the consumer reads an email in some instance, all the other instances will update the email flag, because they implement the observer pattern, and that's all ;)

Comment: Thanks Artem, I did not see any documentation about the behavior so thought of asking here. I will update this ticket if I find different behavior.

Comment: mark messages as read = "true" doesn't prevent duplicate message processing in multi node scenario so we have used spring shedlock  with scheduler to process it only once.

Comment: You also can use a leader election feature from Spring Integration, where only one active instance is going to pull mail box: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#leadership-event-handling. Another feature is to use an Idempotent Receiver advice to prevent duplicates: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, can you edit above answer with your last comment. I can then accept it as final answer.

Comment: OK. Edited my answer. Although comments are really part of the discussion and don't lose a context of the question.